# how do I get cat total - shipping in checkout page?

Tags: magento

I wanted to know the cart total - shipping in the checkout page.So that I can alert user they are $$ away from free shipping.

Any idea how we can do this ?

Thanks
Ab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked on a similar setup, a quick check into the block that is set up provides:

```
 $_totals = $this->getQuote()->getTotals();
```

You should be able to var_dump the array and determine which totals you need. Such as:

```
 $_subtotal = $_totals["subtotal"]->getValue();
```